# How to use a connected/embedded object's groups attribute to authenticate the parent record in AWS AppSync (Amplify)

Tags: authentication, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, velocity, aws-appsync

### Background

In a project I am working on, we are using AWS as the cloud provider and Amplify with AppSync GraphQL to help rapidly build the back end. AppSync in Amplify defaults to having a DynamoDB database so that is what we are using with it.

We are using data-level security so users can only see records they are meant to see in a shared database.

There is a hierarchy whereby a Project object can contain many other objects and we need to ensure that anyone who is authorised to view the Project, can also view everything it contains.

### The Problem

To do this, it was assumed that we could have an `Asset` object with a `projectId` attribute and `project` connection to populate the project details on reading the record. The Project table/object contains a `groups` attribute which we use dynamic group security in the `@auth` directive.

here's an example of the schema:

```
type Project
  @model
  @auth(rules: [
    { allow: groups, groupsField: "groups" }
  ])
{
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  reference: String
  clientId: ID!
  client: Organisation!
    @connection(fields: ["clientId"])
  modifiedById: ID
  changeComment: String
  groups: [String!]
}

type Asset
  @model
  @key(name: "byProjectId", fields: ["projectId"])
{
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  projectId: ID!
  project: Project!
    @connection(fields: ["projectId"])
  completedAt: AWSDateTime
}
```

It is simplified so does not make a lot of sense as written. Ideally, we would use the `@auth` directive to specify the field for the `Asset` type as well like this

```
@auth( allow: groups, groupsField: "project.groups" )
```

We have also attempted to do it manually with a custom resolver written in Velocity (.vtl) which turned out to be very much the same thing:

```
#set( $allowedGroups = $util.defaultIfNull($item.project.groups, []) )
#set( $userGroups = $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.identity.claims.get("cognito:groups"), []) )
#foreach( $userGroup in $userGroups )
    #if( $util.isList($allowedGroups) )    
        #if( $allowedGroups.contains($userGroup) )
            #set( $isLocalDynamicGroupAuthorized = true )
        #end
    #end
    #if( $util.isString($allowedGroups) )
        #if( $allowedGroups == $userGroup )
            #set( $isLocalDynamicGroupAuthorized = true )
        #end
    #end
#end
```

After checking it, I found at the time this resolver is run, the `project` field is null which leads me to think it has not been joined in yet so can't be used as originally planned.

### The Answer?

Is there a way to do this or a more suitable alternative? My concern is that the obvious solution of having all objects having their own groups attribute which contains the parent project's user group name could get very unwieldy as there are upwards of 10k assets to a project and more than just assets to consider.

Am I wrestling with my urge to normalise the data since this is a NoSQL db and we should just duplicate the values and handle that in the code?

Would a User Permission Matrix table be more sensible and would it be easy enough to build into AppSync with Amplify?

Any hints as to how to do this or implement a more suitable solution would be very much appreciated.